# Can't display the outputs of a MATLAB Function block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, display

I have a very simple MATLAB Function block in Simulink where I assign 2 input constants to 2 outputs (x1 to y1 and x2 to y2). Simulink runs without any complaints, however, I cannot see the constants on the displays I have connected to the block outputs (the displays constantly show 0). Any idea what I am missing here?

[image]

```
function [y1,y2] = fcn(x1, x2)

while true
    y1=x1
    y2=x2
end
```

Update: I have also used the Data Inspector to inspect the 2 outputs of the function block and it also reported a value of 0 for both.

Comment: Can you add the content of the function block?

Comment: Sure, I have now updated the question

Comment: Why do you use a while statement in the function? That causes the Matlab function block to never return an output. Remove the while statement and it should be working fine.

Comment: You were absolutely right rinkert, thank you very much. It is been a while since the last time I used function blocks, hence the silly mistake!